# Two trains collision problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

> Consider two trains $A$ and $B$ travelling on a line one towards the
>   other at speed $v_A=v_B=90km/h=25m/s$. When they are $511m$ apart the
>   driver $A$ start braking with deceleration $a_A=1.25m/s^2$ and gives a
>   sound signal. As soon as driver $B$ hears the signal, he brakes with
>   deceleration $a_B$. What is the minumum value of $a_B$ such that the
>   two trains do not collide?

I'm considering the moment in which $B$ hears the signal, after $t^*=\frac{511}{v_{sound}+v_B}=1.4s$, therefore in that moment $A$ is in the position $d_A= 25 (1.4)- \frac{1.25}{2} (1.4)^2=34m$ and $B$ is in the position $d_B=511-25(1.4)=511-35=476 m$.

So the two equation of motion when $t>t^*$ should be:

$x_A(t)=d_A+ v_{A_{0}} (t-t^*)- \frac{a_A}{2} (t-t^*)^2$

With $v_{A_{0}}$ the speed at $t^*$ so $v_{A_{0}}=25-(1.25)(1.4)=23 m/s$

$x_B(t)=d_B -v_{B_{0}}(t-t^*)+ \frac{a_B}{2} (t-t^*)^2$

With $v_{B_{0}}=25m/s$

And the equations of velocity are:

$v_A(t)=v_{A_{0}}-a_A (t-t^*)$

$v_B(t)=-v_{B_{0}}+a_B (t-t^*)$

I tried to find the moment $t'$ in which the two trains would collide (so I tried to solve for $t$ the equation $x_A(t)=x_B(t)$), in order to impose $v_B(t')=0$ and get $a_B$ from that.

Using Mathematica I get $a_B=0.65 m/s^2$ which is wrong because it should be $a_B=1.38 m/s^2$.

I cannot understand where is the mistake in what I tried to do, does anyone have suggestions?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: There is a mistake in your expression for $x_A(t)$ for $t>t^*$. You should notice that train A has started braking before $t^* = 1.4$ s, and so its speed is no longer 25 m/s at that time. Also, proceeding as you did, $a_B$ is the solution of a quadratic equation, which has two roots. The correct one is that for which not only $v_B(t')=0$, but also $v_A(t')=0$.